# Why errors are random in linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, linear-regression

In data science when we study linear regression from a mathematical point of view we often have the following hypothesis:

We have points $y_i = x_i\beta + \epsilon_i$ with $\epsilon_i$ being a random variable.
I don't understand why we talk about a random variable, a probability when everything is deterministic.

If we observe the data $\{(y_i, x_i)\}$ then by taking $\beta = \min_\beta \frac{1}{n}\lVert y_i - x_i\beta \rVert^2$, we can write each of the data as: $y_i = x_i\beta + \epsilon_i$ and thus $\epsilon_i$ is completely deterministic, it is not a random variable. $\epsilon_i$ is simply equal to : $y_i-x_i\beta$.

The same goes for the different hypotheses of application of a linear regression, I don't understand why we need them (average of zero errors, ...). As long as: $\beta = \min_\beta \frac{1}{n}\lVert y_i - x_i\beta \rVert^2$ is well defined we can apply the model on our data without problems

Comment: If you went back to your device and made the measurements again, would you get the exact same $\epsilon_i$ the second time?

Comment: Any real measurement is inherently random to some degree. If 1000 people measure the length of a table to the nearest millimetre they will not all come up with the exact same value.

Comment: @eyeballfrog but data is fixed. We have $\{(y_i, x_i) \}$, which is fixed. We don't make the measurement multiple times.

Comment: Data is fixed *after* the experiment. But the model is trying to predict what the values would be *before* the experiment. After all, even if you don't decide to repeat it (and plenty of people do), some other researchers may want to do the same experiment for themselves, and they almost certainly will get different $\epsilon_i$.

Comment: @ConfusionMatrix $\epsilon_i$ is random and therefore $y_i$ is random. Whenever you make a sample the value of $y_i$ cannot cannot be predicted. Yes, you can do the sample once only. Then the resulting regression line is random. You cannot be sure, that this regression line is equal to a regression line based on the population. And if you make a second sample you will get another regression line which is almost surely not the regression line based on the population.

Comment: Probability is still not well integrated in data science. The field is mostly about industry practice (i.e. it's an engineering field). Linear regression, being a mathematical statistics classic, is a notable exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I think of it is that once we have a data set those values are crystalized and constant. We then attempt to fit a linear regression model on the data set. Since the data points are constant any residual from the linear model is fixed and deterministic.

However, we frequently use models to predict things that we haven't seen. If we got a new data set, the data points are very likely going to be different than the ones in the first data set. They'll have different residuals or distances from the linear model. These residuals are of course $\epsilon_i$.

Since we are not God or someone who can just look into any point in the future to figure out what the particular $X_i$ and $Y_i$ coming our way is, we'll add some amount of uncertainty that our model is not accounting for which is $\epsilon_i$ an unknown, or random, value.